# Wordpress 120 posts and memory isseus

Tags: wordpress

I have about 120 posts on my site. up to 200 visitors per day. Now I am faced with fatal error: memory problems when I visit an administration page or when I add / edit a message.

How can the memory limit increase? I read i can change it in php.ini file but i dont have any access to that file. My host dont want to increase my memory...

Is there other way to increase the memory limit ? (im using wordpress)

I already had deactivated most of the plugins. using gzip response, using wp super cache, optimizing DB on weekly basis, and planning to write short posts

Memory Limit 64 MB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to wp-config.php:

```
define( 'WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT' , '512M' );
define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT' , '512M' );
```